# bean:message is not showing up

Tags: jsp, struts

I have a page index.jsp that has this snippet in it

```
<bean:message key="label.username" />
```

I then have a file called MessageResource.properties  which has:

```
label.username = Login Details
```

and then finally in my strusts-config.xml I have the following line:

```
<message-resources parameter="MessageResource"/>
```

However, the index.jsp does not show the lablel instead it shows the following:

??? label.username ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving full name like below shown